# Issues with heroku run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

When I try and run a database migration for my Rails app on Heroku, I get a standard error. I can run database migrations in my development environment, but get this error when I try to run it through Heroku for our production server.

```
Running rake db:migrate on roomedy... up, run.8811
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to CreateRelationships (20151014160311)
   (1.1ms)  BEGIN
== 20151014160311 CreateRelationships: migrating ==============================
-- create_table(:relationships)
   (15.9ms)  CREATE TABLE "relationships" ("id" serial primary key, "house_id" integer, "user_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL) 
   (3.4ms)  CREATE  INDEX  "index_relationships_on_house_id" ON "relationships"  ("house_id")
   (3.1ms)  CREATE  INDEX  "index_relationships_on_user_id" ON "relationships"  ("user_id")
   -> 0.0310s
-- add_foreign_key(:joined_tables, :houses)
   (10.7ms)  ALTER TABLE "joined_tables" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_fbc117e2f7"
FOREIGN KEY ("house_id")
  REFERENCES "houses" ("id")

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "joined_tables" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "joined_tables" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_fbc117e2f7"
FOREIGN KEY ("house_id")
  REFERENCES "houses" ("id")

   (1.2ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "joined_tables" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "joined_tables" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_fbc117e2f7"
FOREIGN KEY ("house_id")
  REFERENCES "houses" ("id")
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:460:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:724:in `add_foreign_key'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20151014160311_create_relationships.rb:9:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: I think the error message `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "joined_tables" does not exist` is pretty clear. Please double check that the table `joined_tables` exists on your production environment.

Comment: also if you're adding joined_tables in a later migration you need it to exist before you create the constraint so you might need to break your migrations up here.

Comment: To make sure that it exists in my production environment, what do I need to add/look for in production.rb?

Comment: Answered here. You try to alter a table that does not exist. You should run the migration that creates the `joined_table` first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117031/rails-dbmigrate-relation-does-not-exist/34117712#34117712